# Replace image when scrolling up the page and when opening menu

Tags: jquery, image, replace, scrolltop

I found a really nice CodyHouse pop out menu on their website. The problem I am facing, as a total jQuery newb, is that I can't seem to figure out how to replace my logo when...

1. The user is scrolling up
2. The menu is opened using the burger menu

Here is the code that CodyHouse provide and that I am currently using...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//if you change this breakpoint in the style.css file (or _layout.scss if you use SASS), don't forget to update this value as well
var MQL = 1170;

//primary navigation slide-in effect
if($(window).width() > MQL) {
    var headerHeight = $('.cd-header').height();
    $(window).on('scroll',
    {
        previousTop: 0
    }, 
    function () {
        var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        //check if user is scrolling up
        if (currentTop < this.previousTop ) {
            //if scrolling up...
            if (currentTop > 0 && $('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
                $('.cd-header').addClass('is-visible');
            } else {
                $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
            }
        } else {
            //if scrolling down...
            $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible');
            if( currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.cd-header').addClass('is-fixed');
        }
        this.previousTop = currentTop;
    });
}

//open/close primary navigation
$('.cd-primary-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
    $('.cd-menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked'); 
    $('.cd-header').toggleClass('menu-is-open');

    //in firefox transitions break when parent overflow is changed, so we need to wait for the end of the trasition to give the body an overflow hidden
    if( $('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible') ) {
        $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
            $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
        });
    } else {
        $('.cd-primary-nav').addClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
            $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
        }); 
    }
}); });
```

The HTML is...

```
<div class="cd-header">
    <div class="cd-logo"><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Wunderful_Designs_Logo-_-Print_300dpi-_-Royal_Blue_Version.svg" width="250" height="auto"/></a></div>

    <nav>
        <ul class="cd-secondary-nav">
            <li><a href="tel:+448451390151">0845 139 0151</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:hello@wunderful.co.uk">hello@wunderful.co.uk</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- cd-nav -->


    <a class="cd-primary-nav-trigger" href="#0">
        <span class="cd-menu-text">Menu</span><span class="cd-menu-icon"></span>
    </a> <!-- cd-primary-nav-trigger -->
</div>

<nav>
    <ul class="cd-primary-nav">
        <li class="cd-label">About us</li>

        <li><a href="#0">The team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Our services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Our projects</a></li>

        <li class="cd-label">Work with us</li>

        <li><a href="#0">Start a project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Join In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Create an account</a></li>

        <li class="cd-label">Follow us</li>

        <li class="cd-social cd-facebook"><a href="#0">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="cd-social cd-instagram"><a href="#0">Instagram</a></li>
        <li class="cd-social cd-dribbble"><a href="#0">Dribbble</a></li>
        <li class="cd-social cd-twitter"><a href="#0">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<header>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="two-column">
            <div class="column home-intro">
                <div class="block">         
                    <h1>This is Wunderful</h1>
                    <p>My web studio delivers minimalist yet enticing websites that focus on user experience and converting sales.</p>
                    <p>I also support website owners post launch, revising tactics and improving results.</p>
                    <p class="signoff">- Oliver Martin</p>
                    <a href="#"><button class="two-tone">LET'S TALK! <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/wave.svg" width="30px" height="auto" /></button></a>
                    <p style="margin-left: 15px;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wunderful/assets/images/rounded-arrow.svg" width="25px" height="auto"> <small><a href="#">VIEW MY PROJECTS</a></small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="/wp-content/themes/wunderful/assets/images/project-presentation" alt="Lion Windows - Website Project" width="100%" height="auto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

So basically I want to replace .cd-logo img's src with the white version of my logo when the browser window is scrolled up and when the menu button is fired. I'll need the image to go back to the blue version when the user scrolls down and when they close the menu.

Please help, as I can't figure this out. I've tried for hours now :(

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your html mock up, here is whats the jquery code would look like, all you have to so is change my text in the src attribute to the link of the image you want to switch to.

```
 var iScrollPos = 0;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var iCurScrollPos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
        //Scrolling Down
       jQuery('.cd-logo img').attr('src' , ' YOUR IMG URL TO CHANGE TO WHEN SCROLLING DOWN '); 

    }else {

       //Scrolling Up
       jQuery('.cd-logo img').attr('src' , ' YOUR IMG URL TO CHANGE TO WHEN SCROLLING DOWN '); 
    }

    iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;

});
```

Comment: I've marked this as solved, as it works 99.99%. I just have a slight bug in that if you scroll up to the very top of the page the white logo is still showing. You have to scroll down at least 1px to get it to change back to the blue logo. Is there any way of altering the code you provided to fix this? It's near to being 100% perfect, and I think it would be great to sort it.

Here's a video of what I mean... https://streamable.com/a18ip

Answer (score 0):

so this is the answer

```
        var iScrollPos = 0;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var iCurScrollPos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
            //Scrolling Down
           jQuery('#masthead.active .custom-logo-link img').attr('src' , 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/mymain_logo.png'); 

        }else {

           //Scrolling Up
           jQuery('#masthead.active .custom-logo-link img').attr('src' , 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/mywhite_logo.png'); 
        }

        iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;

    });
```

Comment: I like the look of what you have provided in your answer, but where in the jQuery I provided would all that go? Also your references to "#masthead.active" and ".custom-logo-link" are different to the classes I use in the HTML provided. Can you elaborate and alter the classes/ID to match the code I provided? I only ask as I'm a newb and don't fully understand how it will integrate into what I currently have.